# Admin on Rest Mongoose compatible queries

Tags: reactjs, express, mongoose, admin-on-rest

I am using Admin on Rest to create a dashboard for my rest calls. 
The call is going through and I looked at the call in my console.

GET /api/v2/admin/user?_end=10&_order=DESC&_sort=id&_start=0 200 61.102 ms - 2846

But it isn't returning anything, which I assume is because Mongo doesn't take in queries with _end, _order, _start, as well as it uses _id instead of id. 
What would be the best workaround for this? As I can't modify the call going in.

The logic for the endpoint is below. I am also (not pictured) trying to manually create the sorting options but I feel like that isn't efficient.

```js
// routes/admin/user.js
var express = require('express'),
    router = express.Router();

var User = require(__models + 'user');

router.route('/')
.get(function(req, res, next){
  var query = req.query || {};

  User.find(query).then(users => {
    return res.json(users);
  }).catch(err => next(err));
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Can you show the controller logic for this endpoint?

Comment: @Rowland I added my logic, I am also trying to manually create the sort/start/end options but it doesn't seem efficient

Comment: But that's not the endpoint you were seeing in the console. What you shared is for the root

Comment: There's an index.js file that maps it so it is the endpoint in the console
router.use('/user', require('./user'));

Comment: Okay. You can manually build your query object to make the names in the DB in that case

Answer (score 1):

You need to write your own REST Client for creating queries in formats your REST API understands.

https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/RestClients.html#writing-your-own-rest-client

Answer (score 0):

I created a util function to do this for me.

```js
module.exports.getJsonFromUrl = function(query) {
  var result = {};
  query.split("&").forEach(function(part) {
    var item = part.split("=");
    result[item[0]] = decodeURIComponent(item[1]);
  });
  return result;
};
```

And I called it from controller like so

```js
var query = routeUtil.getJsonFromUrl(req._parsedUrl.query);
```